# How do I build an LED driver, where the input is a current source?

Tags: current-source, led-driver

I'm designing a driver to interface four [7-segment digits](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/216/SC40-19SYKWA-246365.pdf) (8V, 20 mA per segment) with an [AS1115 driver](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/588/AS1115_DS000206_1_00-1512924.pdf) (5V supply, constant current outputs). Following an internet source, I have the circuit shown below. I'd understand how to pick the resistors if the chip were a voltage source. However, I'm an electronics novice and not terribly comfortable with current sources. How do I pick the resistor values?

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Current source = no resistors needed but also no choice but to match the LED current to the driver. If you drive two at the time, you will best case have half the brightness on both. Also, CC drivers may or may not like having the LEDs switched in and out. Check the datasheet for the driver. AS1115 seems to be made for the very purpose so probably no issues.

Comment: I can't drive the LEDs directly because the IC is a 5V part and the LEDs want 8V.

Comment: Oh, that will be more tricky. You will be sending 20 mA of base current. Hmm. Do you have an 8+ V rail available?

Comment: I'm using a 5V-9V DC-DC converter.

Comment: Then you will pick your resistor according to (9-8)/R=I.

Comment: Yes, I know how to pick the series limiting resistor that sets the LED current. What I don't know is how to pick all the rest of those resistors around the transistors...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138518/discussion-between-winny-and-ross-tucker).

Comment: This might be an easier way: https://embedded-lab.com/blog/high-voltage-seven-segment-led-display-driver-with-spi-interface/

Comment: @Mattman944 Most excellent find!